# Python curses library not initializing

Tags: python, python-curses

I installed the windows-curses library through pip, and it seemed to install without any issue.

However whenever I try to run a program like this simple one below in gives me this error.

**Code:**

```
import curses
import time

stdscr = curses.initscr()
time.sleep(10)
curses.endwin()
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/elija/OneDrive/Desktop/ASCII_Adventure/temp2.py", line 4, in <module>
    stdscr = curses.initscr()
  File "C:\Users\elija\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\curses\__init__.py", line 30, in initscr
    fd=_sys.__stdout__.fileno())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fileno'
```

I am using python 3.12.1 on Window 10 64bit
The windows-curses version is 2.3.2 (Latest version at this time)

I've tried running the code in IDLE, Command Prompt, and Power Shell, all with the same result.

I also tried running this code to try and debug the issue, but I had the same error.

```
import curses
import os  # Import os for compatibility check

# Compatibility Checks for Curses
try:
    # Initialize curses using windows-curses
    stdscr = curses.initscr()
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error during curses initialization: {e}")
    # If initialization fails, exit the script
    exit(1)

# Check if the terminal supports colors
if not curses.has_colors() or not curses.can_change_color():
    print("Terminal lacks color support")
    # Exit the script if colors are not supported
    exit(1)

# End curses
curses.endwin()
```